# SQL Pecents by Group

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have query and result below.

```
select count(age) countage, age
from table2
group by age
```

and result

```
countage     age
2            1
4            2
4            3
1            4
2            5
8            6
4            7
8            8
1            9
2           10
```

I want to have 2 age group. First group 1 to 5 and second group 6 to 10
I like to have total group 1 and group 2 devide by each count age to get percents 
For example:
Total count for group 1 (age 1 to 5) = 13 and group 2 ( age 6 to 10 ) = 23 
age 1 count = 2 and devide 2 /13 * 100 = 15% 
age 2 count = 4 and devide 4 /13 * 100 = 30% 
and so on for group 1.
Group 2 do the same calculation as group 1
My query but not working well

```
WITH t1 AS 
 (SELECT Age, Count(*) AS n 
  FROM table2
  GROUP BY Age)
SELECT Age, n, 
       (0.0+n)/(COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Age)) 
FROM t1;
```

Need help. Thank you

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want *as data in the question*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want:

```
select (case when age <= 5 then 'group1' else 'group2' end) as age_group,
       count(*),
       count(*) * 1.0 / sum(count(*)) over () as ratio_in_group
from table2
group by (case when age <= 5 then 'group1' else 'group2' end);
```

Or, if you just want this by age, you can do something similar with conditional window functions:

```
select age, count(*) as cnt,
       count(*) * 1.0 / sum(count(*)) over (partition by case when age < 5 then 'group1' else 'group2' end) as ratio_in_group
from table2
group by age;
```

Comment: I need percents by each age not by group